# ConcurrentLinkedQueue and poll()

Tags: java, performance

I'm going to use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and Java as an example to a more general question. Let me first explain the question with regards to `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. Consider:

```java
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
while (true) {
    Integer item = queue.poll();
    if (item != null) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

`ConcurrentLinkedQueue::poll` does not block. So if I was to run this code (and only this code) in its own thread. It would constantly do a redundant operation. Compare this to using something like `LinkedBlockingQueue::take` that blocks until something is available. How much of a difference does it make?

I realize that the question is very vague and specific to the language and data-structure's implementation. But the questions generalizes to something like this:

> How resource consuming is it to run a forever loop that does some small, repetitive operation (like `queue.poll()`)?

Because the operation is small but repetitive, each iteration finishes faster but the loop also runs at a higher frequency, which makes me think that it's worse.

Comment: It seems like `take()` couldn't possibly do worse than this loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "*worse*"? What is your metric for measurement? If a queue-implementation blocks when `poll`ed, it could dead-lock (if nothing is inserted and no timeout can be or is provided). If we do this often enough, we could run in a resource problem (e.g. thread starvation)

Comment: And this implementation wouldn't?  It doesn't have a timeout.  It doesn't do anything different if nothing is inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have an infinite number of operations to execute, scheduled by the `while (true)` loop, you would bring one CPU core to constantly 100% utilisation with the `poll`ing implementation. Which is not a good idea.

On the other hand `take` blocks the thread until an item is available. The thread can be put in the background, while other threads can be executed on the CPU. A blocked thread does not consume resources. It is wake up, when an item is available and only then scheduled to be executed on the CPU.

The context switch of the scheduling of a background thread might give you a slightly slower reaction time (this depends on the operation system implementation of thread scheduling and handling interrupts), but over all it should be way better than putting constantly 100% utilisation on the CPU.

Comment: I would say that `take()` is likely to be "faster," not slower (lower latency is what I really mean).  Since we don't know how much code is in `// do stuff`, it could be a long time before `poll()` is called again.  Worse, edits to the block of code could change the response time significantly, leading to odd and undesired system behavior that could be hard to track down.  Overall, I'd vastly prefer `take()` in its own thread, regardless of the perceived "overhead" of a context switch.